# 404 Not Found - While accessing Folder in Sharepoint from POSTMAN

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error, folder, postman

I am doing a GET request to below URL from POSTMAN to get Folder details and files. But i am always getting 404 Not Found in POSTMAN. ANy suggestion if the URL is wrong.

```
https://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/sites/SidFirstSite/Shared%20Documents/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('/sites/SidFirstSite/Shared%20Documents')
```

Headers -

```
Accept -  application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization - Bearer + access_token
```

When i tried access the below URL i am able to access it and create files in it also.

URL i am able to access -

```
https://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/Shared%20Documents')/Files
```

URL i am unable to access folders is -

```
https://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/sites/SidFirstSite/Shared%20Documents/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(decodedurl='/sites/SidFirstSite/Shared%20Documents')/Files
```

What is the permission i am missing..

Comment: Please add headers you are using in your question. That will be helpful to answer your qustion maybe headers are causing this issue.

Comment: added the headers in question.

Comment: i have updated my question with my few other findings..

Answer (score 1):

In Your URL you have added `Shared%20Documents` after site URL, which is not required.

Try using below URL:

`https://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/sites/SidFirstSite/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')`

**Reference**:

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest).

Also, you need to create the Site level app and add authorization to Postman. Check below article for this:

[Access SharePoint Online using Postman](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/).

Comment: I am getting..."Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Comment: Try updated URL from answer and also check the article given in reference section.

Comment: Have you registered Postman Authorization to SharePoint, [here](https://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/)?

Comment: No i haven't registered for POSTMAN..but registered for Salesforce..still i am able to access and create files for https://learningsfdc.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx .. not for Sites...

Comment: Try registering for postman as given in link and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Found the issue... i didnt created sharepoint Ap at Site level, so thts ahy i was unable to access anything..No after creating ap at Site level, i am able to acess..

Comment: Great. please upvote(^) and accept it as an answer if it helped you.